# Where can we find LHC results talks online?

Tags: resource-recommendations, large-hadron-collider

I'm looking to educate myself on some searches at the LHC, but I find it easier to understand what's going on if I watch a LHC results talk (e.g. by ATLAS, CMS, or an overall summary by a theorist) while I read their paper.

I am currently only familiar with two places where I can occasionally find some videos of talks about LHC results online, at the [Perimeter Institute website](http://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/video-library?qt-videos=1.) and from the [CERN website](https://cds.cern.ch/search?cc=Video%20Lectures&ln=en&jrec=11). Are there any other sites which host videos of past LHC talks?

Comment: I don't know of any, but it might be useful to note that the main sources for keeping up with results are the talks at the largest semi-annual conferences in particle physics, in particular the summary talks at the end of them. The main such conferences are Rencontres de Moriond, ICHEP, EPS. Also, blogs :)